# How can I convert a group of posts into woocommerce products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I created product catalogue on my wordpress site using wp posts and custom fields and now I want to transfer some categories of posts into woocommerce products through Mysql. just copy these posts to woocommerce - how can i do it? The categories remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

you can use : Post Type Switcher http://wordpress.org/plugins/post-type-switcher/faq/ or 
Convert Post Types : http://wordpress.org/plugins/convert-post-types/ or read this post : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/127744/convert-wordpress-posts-to-products-in-woocommerce

Answer (score 0):

I have used this:

```
global $wpdb;
 $wpdb->update(
 $wpdb->posts,
 array( 'post_type' => 'product', ),
 array( 'post_type' => 'post', ),
 // Data Type (available: %s string, %d integer, %f float)
 '%s',
 // SQL "WHERE" clause Type
 '%s'
);
```

and this

```
UPDATE  `wp_posts` SET  `post_type` =  'product' WHERE  `post_type` = 'post';
```